# Alert is not appear from web view in android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview

I use the sample provided by *Google* for demonstrating two way communication between JavaScript and Java ,

ref[1]:

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java

The functionality is working fine. I am able to call JavaScript function
from Java and callback the Java function from JavaScript.

The problem is when I use an alert inside a JavaScript function it won`t
appear, but the functionality inside the function is working properly.

Why does `alert("test")` inside a JavaScript function not appear in Android.
I load the JavaScript in a `web-view`. When I a clicking button in Android
I call the function, but it does not appear.

If anyone knows the problem, pealse help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I use the code from the path                  http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/assets/demo.html                http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webview.requestFocusFromTouch();

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());    

     webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

this code working perfect and shows me alert box..
and this is my 
***test.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya its is working , i made a mistake...instead of using WebChromeClient() straightly as you , i used it as  final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    }  then i use as you said its working

Comment: but is there is any way to change the alert title

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following two lines, my JavaScript works:

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()());
mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following mehtod,

```
WebView wv=new WebView(this);   
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
@Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
    //Required functionality here
    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use WebChromeClient. It will do everything.

```
mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

It will work.